# What is the proper way to create reusable components react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Learning react and building a page where there is lots of input fields.
I want to create components for different input types so later i can use them instead of creating inputs over and over again.

I've wrote something like this but i repeat many things so i thought there might be a better way to do it.

```
class BaseInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <input
        id={this.props.id}
        name={this.props.name}
        type={this.props.type}
        value={this.props.value}
        onChange={this.props.onChange}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        required
      />
    );
  }
}

export function PasswordInput(props) {
  return (
    <BaseInput
      id={props.id}
      name={props.name}
      type="password"
      value={props.value}
      onChange={props.onChange}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
    />
  );
}

export function TextInput(props) {
  return (
    <BaseInput
      id={props.id}
      name={props.name}
      type="text"
      value={props.value}
      onChange={props.onChange}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: I believe this question belongs here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can know if a component is usefull if it takes less line to write at the end, here your BaseInput is just a basic input with less functionnality (you're just forwarding props to the input component). PasswordInput will take only one props less than a real password input. You can't always abstract things. You should look at useForm to abstract the state management and validation of your inputs, it will make your code more maintainable and easier to read.

Comment: I wasn't aware of such a thing exists. Thanks for the comment @jasie

Comment: It looks deep but docs are looking great with nice examples. Thanks @NicolasMenettrier

Answer (score 2):

You can use [spread](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) operator to reduce code.

```
class TextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return <input {...this.props} />;
  }
}

export default TextInput;
```

This way you even don't need a seperate PasswordInput component.

```
<TextInput id="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" />
<TextInput id="password" type="password" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your reusable component is named `FormInput`

The component definition should look like this:

```
const FormInput = (props: any) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value);
  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(props.value);
  }, [props.value])

  return ( 
    <input
       autoComplete={props.autoComplete}
       name={props.name}
       type={props.type}
       id={props.id} 
       value={props.value}
       data-index={props.index} 
       onChange={props.onChange} 
       disabled={props.disabled}
       ariaLabelledBy={props.ariaLabelledBy} 
       required={props.required}/>
  )
};
```

And in the page where you want to use it you can simply invoke the component pass all the props to the component and implement the onChange event handler on the page:

Let's say you want to invoke the Input component on Login page:

```
const LoginPage = (props: any) => {
    ... // you have some useEffect etc. that is related to the business logic of the page

    const handleChange = (event: any) => {
      // put your logic here
    }

   return (
        ... // other HTML elements/components

       <FormInput type="text" onChange={handleChange} id="test" value="John Doe" ... />
   )
};
```